# E: Unable to locate package libqt5scripttools5

Tags: bug-reporting

I'm following a tutorial to compile something, I've followed it to the letter but I'm getting errors when trying to install some of the required packages...

```
chaoss@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libqt5scripttools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libqt5scripttools
```

I've tried `sudo-apt get update` but that hasn't made any difference, please help

Comment: These packages also have the same error: libqt5scripttools5 libqt5svg5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libqt5location5 qtlocation5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qtscript5-dev qtsensors5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev qtquick1-5-dev

Comment: Can you please post the link of the tutorial?